# How to access value from a static C# list

Tags: c#

I have created a static class which contains some static values list. Now I want to access these values out side from this class. I need to know how can I do this? The code example is provided below:

```
public class RoleList
    {

        static public List<RoleDetials> Roles()
        {
            List<RoleDetials> roleDetaildsList = new List<RoleDetials>();
            roleDetaildsList.Add(new RoleDetials
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "admin"
            });
            roleDetaildsList.Add(new RoleDetials
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "sadmin"
            });
            roleDetaildsList.Add(new RoleDetials
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "badmin"
            });

            return roleDetaildsList;
        }


    }


    public class RoleDetials
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I already tried to like below but this way not works as per C# syntax.

```
var allRoles = RoleList.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you forgot to Call `Roles()`? For example `RoleList.Roles()`

Comment: static public List<RoleDetials> Roles() { ... } is not static?

Comment: All answers so far are correct. What they do not explain is that, contrary to your conception, there is no static List in your code. There is a static method that returns a List when called. — Also, as a spelling nitpick, it should be 'RoleDetails' instead of 'RoleDetials'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the static method with

```
var allRoles = RoleList.Roles();
```

Answer (score 2):

To access to data is

```
List<RoleDetials> allRoles = RoleList.Roles();
```

And replace

```
static public List<RoleDetials> Roles()
```

For

```
public static List<RoleDetials> Roles()
```

Comment: As long as `static` comes before the return type it's placement is a matter of style only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method as,

```
List<RoleDetials> roles = RoleList.Roles();
```